# Are there examples of languages where prepositions are treated as nouns/verbs/adjectives instead?

Tags: vocabulary

I am struggling figuring out how to consider "function" words (like particles or prepositions) in a conlang. Verbs, nouns, and adjectives have been relatively straightforward but not these function words. Here are [70 prepositions](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-list.htm) from English:

> aboard, about, above, across, after, against, along, amid, among, anti, around, as, at, before, behind, below, beneath, beside, besides, between, beyond, but, by, concerning, considering, despite, down, during, except, excepting, excluding, following, for, from, in, inside, into, like, minus, near, of, off, on, onto, opposite, outside, over, past, per, plus, regarding, round, save, since, than, through, to, toward, towards, under, underneath, unlike, until, up, upon, versus, via, with, within, without

Some are movement/location/position based, some are containment, etc..

Are there any languages which lack treating these kinds of words like this, and instead treat them as nouns, verbs, or adjectives/adverbs ("features"/modifiers)? If not, why not? If so, what are some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swahili has very few actual prepositions; in most cases where English would use a preposition, Swahili uses a noun.

> Paka iko ndani ya sanduku.
> cat located inside of box
> *The cat is in the box.*
>
> Paka iko juu ya meza.
> cat located top of table
> *The cat is on the table.*
>
> Nitakwenda nyumbani baada ya kesho.
> I-FUT-go home-LOC after of tomorrow
> *I'll go home after tomorrow.*

These "prepositions", *ndani*, *juu*, *baada*, are syntactically just class-9 nouns meaning "the inside", "the top", and "the time after"; as nouns, they can be joined to other nouns with *-a* "of". Swahili really likes its nouns and uses them in many cases where English would want a preposition, an adverb, an adjective, etc.

Notably, the main reason English has so many prepositions is because they used to be an open class. All the ones starting with "be-", for example, are derived from nouns.

Comment: Cool! Where can I find a list of those things in Swahili. Hoping that even words like "with" and "as" and "to" are treated as nouns as well :)

Comment: @Lance Any good dictionary should include them. Swahili still has some true prepositions, but far fewer than English; most spatial and temporal relationships are indicated with nouns. Others function as conjunctions: "with" for example is often conveyed by "and".

Comment: I have the [Swahili Learners' Reference Grammar](https://www.amazon.com/Swahili-Learners-Reference-Grammar-Thompson/dp/1597030074), but it doesn't explicitly say the reasoning behind what is a preposition and what is like you are saying, which is kind of unhelpful. Also it appears that some things I asked for are still prepositions in Swahili (like "by").

Comment: @Lance There's not really a "reasoning" behind it; some things are prepositions and some are relational nouns and that's just how it works.

Comment: Okay, well the idea of [relational nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_noun) is new to me, so that is helpful as well.

Comment: @Lance For whatever reason, these Swahili nouns are not usually called relational nouns, but I don't know why.

Comment: See also these questions on [linguistics.se]: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31069/9781 and https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31075/9781

Answer (score 1):

I faced English prepositions with the same bewilderment.

Anybody should... I drew out a [list of adposition "functions"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bG4Og2aQYJ-iJDDveFMIeJowi32L2tbdCx1IwD3_vyw/edit?usp=sharing) using Spanish's smaller set. I am usually looking at my own table, not the English/Spanish, but I do not recall needing to add any adpositions to that list in many dozen (maybe 100+ by now) pages of different translations.

For my own conlang, I worked up a set of "position" verbs which filled the functions through their several verb forms,

intransitive

- "Fred ins" being "Fred enters"

or transitive with objects in different cases

- "Fred ins ACC-yard" being "Fred is inside the yard"
- "Fred ins DAT-yard" being "Fred goes into the yard"
- "Fred ins GEN-house" being "Fred goes in from the yard"
- "Fred ins INS-house" being "Fred goes through the yard"

I had extra spaces left on my VerbxCase multiplication table. I assigned those to other common verbs: "Fred fars" -> "Fred is unfamiliar."